# VBA- four lines(can you explain this in plain english please?)

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range(pRngBoardSize)) Is Nothing Then
'if the target is within the given range this part of the code gets activated
Cancel = True

End If

End Sub
```

I came up with my own interpretation but could you make sure it's right and can you tell me why we are using cancel=true?
Thank you!

Comment: A Google search for `BeforeRightClick` [explains everything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192993.aspx).

Comment: `Cancel = True` cancels the default action (ie. displaying the context menu)  You could easily have googled that though...

Comment: @KenY-N, Hi Ken! I understand the before right click and that this code is to diable the right click but i am having difficulty understanding  cancel=true , and what it does in this case

Comment: @TimWilliams, Thank for replying! I guess I could googled it. I just wanted to make sure what I have guessed for "if not intersect.." to be correct, too. I am very new to VBA and even when I read explanations online, they sound like an Alien language. Again, thanks for taking time to reply to my (may seem too easy) question:)

Comment: Implied is `ByRef Cancel As Boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when we right click on a worksheet, what we get is the right click pop-up menu.

therefore if you set `Cancel = True`, you are cancelling the pop-up when it tries to appear, effectively the user who do the right click will not see the pop-up.

the name of the sub says it all `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick`, it is a routine that runs at the very moment just before RightClick action is really executed, hence enabling you to still give the command `Cancel` if you wish it not to continue.

what your code seems to do is, if the `Target` cells is not overlapping a predefined region `pRngBoardSize`, then right click on the `Target` cells will not bring up the pop-up menu.

Comment: Thanks you very much, KS! Reading the other comments, I just started learning VBA and thought I was too stupid for not understanding what the google search showed for cancel=true and if not intersect. I really appreciate you taking time to explain this for this newbie.